# Change octopress git commit folder

Tags: git, github, octopress

I am using octopress to create my blog at **username.github.com/title**,
where title is the title of the blog.

In the `_config.yml`, I have configured the `permalink: /:title/`

It now creates the blog at **username.github.com/title** but when I commit it, it creates a folder with the title on the root of the directory instead of it being inside the blog folder.

How do you change it so that it commits inside the blog folder so that all my blogs are grouped in one folder, while still having my blogs at **username.github.com/title**?

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try as follows in `_config.yml`

```
root: /
permalink: /blog/:year/:month/:day/:title/
```